# A Foreign Constraint fail

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm  having an issue with a part of my Website. You can Import an excel file, this file will create products and link them to a categorie.
When I import my excel, Some lines are working and some others no. the error message is the following :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shop`.`produit_categorie`, CONSTRAINT `FK_produit_categorie_categorie_id` FOREIGN KEY (`categorie_id`) REFERENCES `categorie` (`categorie_id`))

Here is the code when the excel is imported :

```php
 public static function saveData(PDO $bdd, PHPExcel_Worksheet $objWorksheet, $constructeur_id, $catalogue_id) {

/* . . . */
                     else if ($type == RowType::PRODUIT) {

                        $data_array = self::getRowData($row);
                        $taxe_id = self::generateTaxe($bdd);
                        $produit_id = self::generateProduit($bdd, $data_array, $constructeur_id, $taxe_id);
                        self::generatePrixProduitCatalogue($bdd, $data_array, $produit_id, $catalogue, $catalogue_id, $cpt_row_full);
                        self::generateCategorieProduit($bdd, $categorie_id_courante, $produit_id);

                        $code_retour = "200";


                    } else if ($type == RowType::PLATEFORME) {
                        // si la ligne est autre chose que produit ou info -> donc intitule plateforme
                        $code_retour = "200";
                    } else {
                        // erreur
                        $code_retour = "400_" . $cpt_row;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                $cpt_row_full++;

            }// fin IF "ligne pas vide"
            $cpt_row++;
        }// fin foreach
        echo $code_retour;
    }
```

So the products are created noramlly in my Database. But what I don't understand is why some products are working correctly and some other (on the same excel, same model but 2 lines later ans the next one is working).

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Presumably the id defined in your `produit_categorie` cell actually exists in `categorie.categorie_id` - from the error, it _sounds_ like you're trying to link to a non-existent category.

Comment: The fact is, on my excel you only have 1 category, So all the products you import are links to the same That's why i don't understand why it works for some and not for some others...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if you have any value set to 0 or blank in the excel sheet or if a non-existant ID is trying to be assigned in excel.

Comment: Yes, I've already check, If a valur already exist I will not create a new one. No value set to 0 or incorrect value, i check if before import it